# Trouble setting correct text from an array, using Knockout

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I am looping through an array:

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: devices">
```

one of my columns holds a **clientId**

```
<td  data-bind="text: clientId"></td>
```

but rather than that clientId, I would like to output **lastName** , which is located inside another observableArray of Client objects:

```
let Client = function(clientId, lastName){
    this.clientId   = ko.observable(clientId);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(lastName);
}

self.client           = ko.observableArray();
```

so somehow, in my table column, I need to search through the client array, find the current clientId (we are in loop) , and then print out the lastName in the TD rather than clientId.

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$root` you can get the root instance of the data model, so you can find the client in the client() observableArray.
Supposing you have a `findClient(id)` function in root, you should:

```
<td data-bind="text: $root.findClient(clientId())"></td>
```

Comment: and then in the function I find the last name, and then "return lastName" ?

Comment: I am not in front of computer, but would something like this work?

self.findClient = function (clientId) {
        //alert(clientId());
        
        for (var i = 0; i < self.clients().length; i++) {
            if (self.clients()[i].clientId == clientId) {
                return self.clients()[i].lastName;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Ok, this is not working. I know I am close, but not printing out the lastName:


    // Given a clientId, return the lastName
    self.findClient = function (clientId) {
    
        for (var i = 0; i < self.client().length; i++) {
            if (self.client()[i].clientId() == clientId) {   
                return self.client()[i].lastName();
            }
        }
    }

// Html
 <td style="font-weight: bold" data-bind="text: $root.findClient(clientId)"></td>

Comment: After debugging the above code, your suggestion worked. Thank you